# Android MusicPlayer no object after resuming activity

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I created activity which plays songs. And i have class which loads song from sd-card and puts it in MediaPlayer for reproduction. If MediaPlayer is actually playing song and i switch to launcher by pressing home button, and later try to go back to activity, i loose MediaPlayer object. (Even though it is still playing) If i try to switch to new song, that new song will just start playing over old song even though i called pause method on previous song. Anyone knows how can i solve this problem?

Comment: initialize your object onResume() if it's not null

Comment: MediaPlayer object is present in activity fields (in onResume() method I checked with debugger), but i think its state is not proper. I DO NOT want to make new object, i want to use old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `MediaPlayer` in a `Service` and bind `Activity` with the `Service` to control it. The `MediaPlayer` can't be limited by the life cycle of the `Activity` if you intend for it to continue playing when the `Activity` does not exist.

Comment: I tried that approach first, but i had huge problems with Intent. I only found tutorials for sending simple commands, but in my case that Service would need to be able to access data in activity. If you know any advanced tutorial on this it would be helpful, especially something with bidirectional communication. (Not those from developers website, cause they are so simple that they are not helpful at all.)

Comment: Without more specifics, I can't say anything with certainty, but accessing data in the Activity sounds like it can be resolved by using callbacks or sending messages appropriately. I assure you, using a Service is the right way to go, though. The [developers' page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) on bound Services shows how to establish two-way communication with Handlers/Messengers (look under Using a Messenger). If you have specific problems, update the question or make a new one & I will be happy to help.

Comment: I don't know why someone had to complicate stuff in this communication between Activity and Service but he succeeded. This tutorial is a good one i will report back.

Comment: I succeeded in connecting these two, but there is only one problem. Service gets restarted every time i switch back to my app from home screen. Do you know what might be causing problem?

Comment: If you are not doing so already, you need to start the Service with an Intent (call `startService` from your Activity) - and also call `stopSelf` appropriately inside the Service. The lifetime of a Service can be decided in two ways: through the explicit start/stop mechanism, or via bound components. If your Activity is the only thing bound to it, the Service is killed when you unbind (and would need to be restarted when bound again). Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for more info.

Comment: Actually i made some mistakes in my code also, but this last did the trick. :P Thanks Dave.